# latex bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

am using texpad on Mac. Trying to insert references.

Is package `cite` is enough? any other package I have to use to be able to insert bibliography?

am trying to insert bibliography instead of using `\bibitem`, how?

where I am making mistake?

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{aref.bib}  %here just name of the file? .tex? .bib?
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! You are mixing two different ways of defining your bibliography. One uses `thebibliography` and `\bibitem`. The other uses a `.bib` file and `\bibliographystyle`. Get rid of `thebibliography` environment. then use pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex to compile.

Comment: I tried:  \bibliographystyle{plain}
             \bibliography{a.bib} it is not working. Also in text I see "?" instead of citations

Comment: Try without the `.bib`.

Comment: Now still I cannot see References, and it text I see [?citationkey]. If I want to write references using \bibitem, what is the format? which order I have to write details? author, year, title, publication? for books, journals, url will be different?

Comment: If you want to use `\bibitem` then don't use `\bibliographystyle` or `\bibliography` and use the `thebibliography` environment instead. How you should order and format the details depends on the style you are using. With that method, you get to determine the exact format of every entry. There is no right or wrong here: it all depends on the style you are using. (Doing it inconsistently is always wrong but as long as you stick to the style you are meant to use or to one style of your choice, it is fine.)

Comment: It sounds to me as if you did not run `bibtex` or you did not run (pdf)latex twice afterwards. Or you got errors which you've not mentioned.

Comment: @Pablo Suggest you take a moment and read http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management  While not covering all the fine points of bibliographies, this is the document I always sent students to first for most LaTeX questions. And for what you want, I believe this will be a great resource for you.

Answer (score 1):

When using BibTeX (or biblatex), one should not insert the instructions `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` and `\end{thebibliography}`. These instructions are needed only if one builds the bibliography entirely "by hand".

Assuming your bib entries are in file called `aref.bib`, you should write

```
\bibliography{aref}
```

Note that the filename extension, `.bib`, is *not* provided. Incidentally, the order of the entries in the bib file, and the order of the fields within each entry, is immaterial to BibTeX and biblatex.

If you use BibTeX, as would seem to be the case from your code snippets, you also need to

- insert `\cite{<key>}` instructions wherever appropriate and needed in the document
- provide one `\bibliographystyle{<some_style>}` instruction somewhere in the document, either in the preamble or in the body of the document, and
- issue a `\bibliography{<bibfile>}` instruction where you want the References section to show up.

Whenever you add new `\cite` instructions (or delete old ones), you need to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

Answer (score 0):

To use BibTex Harvard Style use the following packages in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ExampleFile.bib}
```

Or if you want numeric style of references use:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ExampleFile.bib}
```

In this example the bib file should be in the same directory as the tex file and contains references such as:

```
@article{arts1999chocolate,
  title={Chocolate as a source of tea flavonoids},
  author={Arts, Ilja CW and Hollman, Peter CH and Kromhout, Daan},
  journal={The Lancet},
  volume={354},
  number={9177},
  pages={488},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

If you wish to cite this in your document use:

```
\cite{arts1999chocolate}
```

and to print references

```
\printbibliography
```

To see examples of how references should be printed either use google scholar or google the specific style for that reference

So a complete MWE for your tex file would be

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ExampleBib.bib} 
\begin{document}

test citation \citep{arts1999chocolate}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and your .bib file would be

```
@article{arts1999chocolate,
  title={Chocolate as a source of tea flavonoids},
  author={Arts, Ilja CW and Hollman, Peter CH and Kromhout, Daan},
  journal={The Lancet},
  volume={354},
  number={9177},
  pages={488},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Comment: have to add \usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ExampleFile.bib}  in preamble? got errors

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: run it again, now cannot see Bibliography and References. in text, I see Cite keys instead of citation.

Comment: have you run the MWE I put in my answer?

Comment: Typically, `.bib` files are not in the same directory. They certainly don't need to be. Mine are in `~/texmf/bibtex/bib/`, for example so that all documents can use the same databases.

Comment: Sure, I just meant for ease sake without having to worry about adding relative paths. But I should edit that, I didn't mean they should always be in the same directory rather in this case it should be.

Comment: yes, changes \cite to 'citep, added \usepackages, just not sure in preamble, what do you mean by "ExampleBib"? also at the end used \printbibliography, cannot see the correct result

Comment: guess the only way is to add them one by one by \bibitem, but do not know the format of \bibitem, how it will change for books, journals, papers, url?

Comment: So create a new document and save it as ExampleBib.bib . In this new document paste the reference and rerun. You don't need to add them one by one. To see how it changes google bibtex format for xxx

Comment: Can you add a MWE of your .bib file and .tex file to your question to help work out what is wrong

Comment: Thanks so much, it is working now, just one thing more, how can I change he style so that I can see the citation in text like "[1]" and numbered in Bibliography section?

Comment: No worries, thats just changing the style so use style=numeric

Comment: References will be printed in alphabetical order anyway if you add more than one